# How to simplify this $(x+x+8+1)^3 +(x+x+8+1) = 1998$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to simplify this $(x+x+8+1)^3 +(x+x+8+1) = 1998$. Hi, guys, I am a bit unsure how to simplify this, I know I can expand it to get a polynomial but it will take too long and this is a multiple choice I assume there is a simpler way to do this?

Comment: $8+1$ is usually written as $9$.

Comment: Can you solve the equation $y^3+y=1998$ ? then maybe you can deduce your solutions

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives $2 x^3 + 27 x^2 + 122 x = 315$.

Comment: Guys i am trying to avoid polynomials my question is are there methods to simplify the following?

Comment: What are the answer choices? There may be quick ways to rule some of them out.

Comment: Yes.  Also, are we trying to solve for x?

Comment: yes solving for x, but can you simplify the question?

Comment: What about factoring out the $2x+9$ [if you mean $x+x$ as $2x$] and see if one can match factors of $1998$ with the two factors...

Comment: @coffeemath I’ve actually tried that.  X is non integer

Comment: @Negrawh since it is an MCQ can you please provide the choices?

Answer (score 1):

If you are given a multiple choice and at the same time you ask for a fast solution, chances are you need to check for, I dunno, the last digit of your expression on the left, so that it matches 8.

Comment: Yes, but you are making an assumption.  How can you be sure x is an integer? (It isn’t)

Comment: What else can I do besides making an assumption if the question is stated this way? I just hope it helped and I assumed correctly. Your point is absolutely valid. If the x is not an integer, then my approach fails.

Comment: I already got the answer but i just want to know can i simplify more

Answer (score 0):

By the Cardano's formula we obtain an unique real root:
$$2x+9=\sqrt[3]{999+\sqrt{999^2+\frac{1}{27}}}+\sqrt[3]{999-\sqrt{999^2+\frac{1}{27}}}$$